# How to get Delta/KLM to allow excess baggage for nonprofit charity to Uganda?

Tags: luggage, delta-air-lines, klm, uganda

Does anyone know how I can get the extra baggage fee waived for materials I am taking to Uganda to a school/orphanage? I am the E.D. for a U.S. nonprofit, and it seems that we should be able to get some help with this, but I have no idea how to request this. A few years back I tried through Delta customer service, sending an email but got no response.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a Google search on Delta community involvement found LaSandra Boykin, Lead Project Manager, Community Engagement, 404-715-3680 lasandra.boykin@delta.com

Comment: A Delta gate manager said that the gate representatives cannot approve a waiver. She said that a request needs to be given to the HA dept. for possible approval.

Answer (score 6):

[Delta Air Lines Baggage Waiver Process and Application](https://public.conxport.com/delta/baggagewaiver/home.aspx)

> Delta Air Lines Baggage Waiver program waives the baggage fees and
>   assists qualifying charitable organizations traveling on international
>   humanitarian missions. This information is provided to help groups
>   seeking consideration of this type of waiver.
>
> Delta receives a large number of baggage waiver requests annually, and
>   while they are all great causes, unfortunately we cannot approve them
>   all. Please do not assume your waiver will be approved, but wait to
>   receive a reply after submitting the necessary information in the
>   application.
>
> Baggage waiver requests must be submitted 14 business days prior to
>   departure date but no more than 30 days in advance in order to be
>   considered. In order to qualify for a baggage waiver exception your
>   reservation must be paid in full and ticketed.

https://mobile.twitter.com/Delta/status/814509120078417920

Answer (score 1):

I have just called both Delta and KLM. I am traveling on a Delta/KLM flight to Malawi through Johannesburg. The answer I received is KLM does NOT offer waivers for humanitarian aid baggage.

Comment: Did Delta provide an answer as well?